# Save value while in php while loop

Tags: php, html

Trying to create buttons with `rule` as the name on the button and `desc` as the value it passes on. But this is just putting `$name` on the button. What am i doing wrong?

```
<?php    
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM db_Rules");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
 $desc = $row['desc'];
 $name = $row['rule'];
?>
      <button onclick="myFunction($desc)">$name</button>
<br>
<?php
 }
?>
```

Comment: use PHP code block and echo your variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to echo out the result whilst looping.

```
<button onclick="myFunction(<?php echo $desc; ?>)"><?php echo $name; ?></button>
```

Full code:

```
<?php
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM db_Rules");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $desc = $row['desc'];
    $name = $row['rule'];
?>
    <button onclick="myFunction(<?php echo $desc; ?>)"><?php echo $name; ?></button>
    <br>
<?php } ?>
```

Or echo it out within the php tags to being with, rather than closing and opening them again:

```
echo "<button onclick='myFunction($desc)'>$name</button>";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<button onclick="myFunction(<?php echo $desc; ?>)"><?php echo $name; ?></button>
```

You need to write it out in php

Answer (score 1):

You have to `echo` the PHP variables in order to get its value in HTML elements.

```
 <button onclick="myFunction(<?php echo $desc;?>)"><?php echo $name;?></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP is for PHP. Wrap your function and the name variable with the  `PHP code block.`

`<button onclick="myFunction(<?php echo $desc ?>);"><?php echo $name; ?></button>`

Answer (score 1):

You've forgot to put php tags around your php variables.

```
<?php    
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM db_Rules");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
 $desc = $row['desc'];
 $name = $row['rule'];
?>
      <button onclick="myFunction(<?php echo $desc;?>)"><?php echo $name;?></button>
<br>
<?php
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not echoing anything, just HTML

```
<?php    
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM db_Rules");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$desc = $row['desc'];
$name = $row['rule'];
?>
<button onclick="myFunction(<?=$desc?>)"><?=$name?></button>
<br>
<?php
}
?>
```

That's if you have short_tags enabled. Otherwise

```
<?php echo $desc; ?>
```

and

```
<?php echo $name; ?>
```

would work

Comment: Don't forget `;` after the variable. Even though it works in this instance, it's good practice

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php    
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM db_Rules");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
 $desc = $row['desc'];
 $name = $row['rule'];
?>
  <button onclick="myFunction(<?= $desc?>)"><?= $name?></button>
<br>
<?php
 }
?>
```

The thing is, that you were not echoing your variables in HTML (your variables were not parsed by interpreter)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php    
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM db_Rules");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
 $desc = $row['desc'];
 $name = $row['rule'];
?>

  <button onclick="myFunction('<?php echo mysql_real_escape_string($desc)?>')"><?php echo $name;?></button>  
  <br />

<?php }?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Note: If you want to use php code inside the html then you should always use php tags

```
<?php 
// Write php code here
?>
```

Thats why you should replace this below line

```
<button onclick="myFunction($desc)">$name</button>
```

with

```
<button onclick="myFunction(<?php echo $desc; ?>)"><?php echo $name; ?></button>
```

and the second way is to write html inside the php tag

```
echo '<button onclick="myFunction('.$desc.')">'.$name.'</button>';
```